# .Net Core Async Await is not continuing Execution

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I have a list of tasks, that will call a webservice restfully. I begin the execution of them when calling `downloadTasksQuery.ToList()`. At that point I would like to process each task as they finish, and add the Distance to the database as soon as it finishes.

When I watch this in the console. All records seem to print to the console all at the same time, and I see the outputis from this line. `Console.WriteLine(" Google Distance : " + d.google_distance);`

The number of times it prints to the console is the number that were in the List of Tasks to begin with.

```
IEnumerable<Task<Distances>> downloadTasksQuery =
    (from tup in urlList select ProcessURL(tup));

List<Task<Distances>> downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToList();

while (downloadTasks.Count > 0)
{
    Task<Distances> thisFinished = await Task.WhenAny(downloadTasks);

    downloadTasks.Remove(thisFinished);
    try
    {
        Distances d = await thisFinished;
        if (d.has_error == false)
        {
            dr.Add(d);
        }
        else
        {
            dr.AddError(d);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" Google Distance : " + d.google_distance);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Deleted task, did not save data");
    }
}
```

> Process URL

```
private static async Task<Distances> ProcessURL(Tuple<string, int, string> tup)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Distances d = new Distances();
    try
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
               //// Post is required by the web api
            var stringTask = client.PostAsync("https://website.com" + tup.Item1, new StringContent("null"));

            var msg2 = await stringTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            d = FromXml<Distances>(msg2.Trim());

        }

    catch (Exception e)
        {
            d.has_error = true;
        }
    d.state_student_identifier = tup.Item3;
    d.student_transportation_id = tup.Item2;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Any what does `ProcessURL` do? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet I have provided more detail.

Comment: This would seem to be better suited for ContinueWith

Comment: The obvious first step is to add timestamps to all your logs, and add logging to `ProcessURL`. Maybe all the tasks really *are* finishing at the same time? Or maybe the console is buffered?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest utilizing `ContinueWith` as it seems more suited for what you are trying to do:

```
var runningTasks = urlList.Select(tup => ProcessURL(tup)
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        var d = task.Result;
        if (d.has_error)
            dr.AddError(d);
        else
            dr.Add(d);
        Console.WriteLine(" Google Distance : " + d.google_distance);
    }));
await Task.WhenAll(runningTasks);
```